# Declare global variable in NodeJS

Tags: typescript

I am currently using this construct to make a global `LOG` available:

```
declare global {
  let LOG: Logger;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
declare namespace globalThis {
  let LOG: Logger;
}

globalThis.LOG = new Logger();
```

Yes, it works, but I need to declare it twice. Why?

BONUS question: How to be smarter?

Comment: Just FWIW, I'd suggest exporting `LOG` from a module instead and importing it where you need it. Creating additional global variables is generally a not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Because the interface of the global namespace isn't the same as the interface of `globalThis`; the latter is a subset of the former. (You can have global variables that aren't properties of the global object, via global-scope `let`, `const`, and `class`.) They're defined distinctly in TypeScript. If this had all been done at the same time maybe the global namespace would use an intersection with the interface of `globalThis`, but `globalThis` was only defined quite recently (and/or there may be other reasons it can't be done that way).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solutions was to turn `let` into `var`:

```
declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var LOG: Logger;
}

global.LOG = new Logger();
```